# How to build some project configurations with msbuild

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, googletest

The gtest's msvc directory has the gtest project file, and opening it with Visual Studio enables me to select the build out of 8 configurations(gtest/gtest_main/gtest_prod_test/gtest_unittest x release/debug) with Batch Build.

How can I do the same thing with *msbuild* tool? For example, how can I tell msbuild to build gtest/Debug or gtest_unittest/Release?

Comment: See a good post with msbuild and devenv examples http://miteshsureja.blogspot.com.au/2012/04/how-to-build-solution-or-project-from.html

Comment: You don't want to put the Solution in the question. Solutions should be put as an answer.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
MSBuild projectfile /property:Configuration=Debug
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171452%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: Or /p:Configuration=Debug

Comment: You can also set the platform with `/property:Platform=Win32`.

Answer (score 2):

Kyle Alons's answer works fine. When I run solution file that has four projects, it generates the release version of  each project.

```
msbuild gtest-md.sln /property:Configuration=Release
```

I could run each project as follows, but the output names are based on solution name, so I need to modify to get correct results.

```
msbuild gtest-md.vcxproj /property:Configuration=Release
```

The solution was to specify target as follows.

```
msbuild gtest-md.sln /target:gtest-md /property:Configuration=Release
```